# Mac OS: how to determine path is file or directory

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, filesystems, nsfilemanager

I have a path and I want to know, is this directory or a file. Pretty simple, but I have a problem. Here's my path:

```
NSString *file = @"file://localhost/Users/myUser/myFolder/TestFolder/";
```

or

```
NSString *file = @"file://localhost/Users/myUser/myFolder/my_test_file.png";
```

Here is my code:

```
BOOL isDir;


// the original code from apple documentation: 
// if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)
// but even my if returns me "not ok" in log

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:&isDir])
{

     NSLog(@"directory");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"not ok");
}
```

files and dirs on this pathes are exists and they are ok. But I thinks problem could be in it. But I don't know why. Help me with this please.

By the way, I get path from another method:

```
   NSArray *contentOfMyFolder = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:urlFromBookmark
              includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLContentModificationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedNameKey]
                                 options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                   error:nil];
```

after this in for loop, I get items that stored in array `contentOfMyFolder`
and get path like this:

```
 for (id item in contentOfMyFolder) {
     NSString *path = [item absoluteString]; 
 }
```

I thinks this is perfectly valid path for method `fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL)isDir`

Where the problem could hide?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
NSString *path = [item absoluteString];
```

because that creates a string representation of the URL, such as

```
file://localhost/Users/myUser/myFolder/TestFolder/
```

and that is not what `fileExistsAtPath:` expects.
What you need is the `path` method to convert the URL to a path:

```
for (NSURL *item in contentOfMyFolder) {
    NSString *path = [item path];
    BOOL isDir;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        if (isDir) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a directory", path);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a file", path);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Oops, %@ does not exist?", path);
    }
}
```

---

***Alternatively,*** you can ask the URL for its "directory property":

```
for (NSURL *item in contentOfMyFolder) {
    NSNumber *isDir;
    NSError *error;
    if ([item getResourceValue:&isDir forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
        if ([isDir boolValue]) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a directory", item);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a file", item);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
}
```